# AJAX vs. jQuery: What Are The Differences?

Tags: web

I'm particularly interested in understanding how they differ in terms of handling asynchronous requests, manipulating the DOM, and overall impact on web development practices.

I was experimenting with implementing AJAX and jQuery in small web development examples to see how they perform in terms of making asynchronous requests and manipulating the DOM